# Accordion background-image's size

Tags: html, css, image, accordion, image-size

I've made a horizontal accordions with background-images, but the images are quite big compared to the width of the accordions. I want the accordions to downsize the background-images, right now I'm only seeing the center of each background images.

Here's my code: (*sample*)

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.accordion ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.accordion ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  width: 16.666%;
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.accordion ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460500063983-994d4c27756c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=27c2758e7f3aa5b8b3a4a1d1f1812310");
}
.accordion ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460378150801-e2c95cb65a50?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=1b5934b990c027763ff67c4115b6f32c");
}
.accordion ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458400411386-5ae465c4e57e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=47756f965e991bf72aa756b410929b04");
}
.accordion ul li:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452827073306-6e6e661baf57?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=c28fd5ea58ed2262a83557fea10a6e87");
}
.accordion ul li:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452215199360-c16ba37005fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=408c70a6e88b50949c51e26424ff64f3");
}
.accordion ul li:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1442551382982-e59a4efb3c86?format=auto&auto=compress&dpr=1&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1920&h=1280&q=80");
}
.accordion ul:hover li {
  width: 8%;
}
.accordion ul:hover li:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
.accordion ul:hover li:hover a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.accordion ul:hover li:hover a * {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .accordion {
    height: auto;
  }
  .accordion ul li,
  .accordion ul li:hover,
  .accordion ul:hover li,
  .accordion ul:hover li:hover {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
  }
}
.about {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
}
.about a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.about a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="accordion">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a **fixed width** for your images to see the full image instead of just the center of it.

see fiddle.

If you will be using huge images, I would be better to use 
`background-size:cover` instead.

Comment: The "100% 100%" did the job. It creates a new problem though.
I don't know if you can see this page (it's not mine, but it's where I got the idea from).
http://www.t-randeris.dk/cases.aspx
When holding the mouse over the image the size is perfect, but when the mouse is moved away, it "squeezes" the image together instead of just "hiding" the rest of the picture.

Comment: yes it squeezs since its width is basing from the width of the accordions and since its a background image. unlike the accordion from the link you gave. you can try setting a fixed width for you image. I made a [fidde](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xY7tx/2477/). pls check if this is right

Comment: But yours still doesn't show the entire picture (or does it)?
I tried using "background-size: cover" and this seems to be the best option so far. It zooms in a tiny bit, but it's much better than before.

Comment: I does shows the entire picture i guess. You said u will be using huge images so i think i would be better to use `background-size:cover`. Hope I helped. should i update my answer so u can accept it?

Comment: Yes please, then I'll accept it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As you're currently using the images as background, you have a handy CSS property available to you right now.

MDN - Background Size: [Contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

Comment: I don't want it to be as large as possible though? I want it to fit.
I tried using "background-size: cover" and this seems to work okay (it zooms in a tiny bit, but it's much better than before)